# scala class constructor parameters

Tags: scala, constructor, scope, immutability

What's the difference between:

```
class Person(name: String, age: Int) {
  def say = "My name is " + name + ", age " + age
}
```

and

```
class Person(val name: String, val age: Int) { 
  def say = "My name is " + name + ", age " + age
}
```

Can I declare parameters as `var`s, and change their values later? For instance,

```
class Person(var name: String, var age: Int) {

  age = happyBirthday(5)

  def happyBirthday(n: Int) {
    println("happy " + n + " birthday")
    n
  }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need clarification in constructor definition syntax in scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757616/need-clarification-in-constructor-definition-syntax-in-scala)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

For the first part the answer is scope:

```
scala> class Person(name: String, age: Int) {
     |   def say = "My name is " + name + ", age " + age
     | }

scala> val x = new Person("Hitman", 40)

scala> x.name
<console>:10: error: value name is not a member of Person
              x.name
```

If you prefix parameters with `val`, `var` they will be visible from outside of class, otherwise, they will be private, as you can see in code above.

And yes, you can change value of the var, just like usually.

Comment: It's somewhat more subtle than a public / private distinction. Without a property keyword (`val` or `var`) the constructor parameters will only be stored in a field at all if they're used in a method body. If they're used only in constructor code _and_ are not prefixed with `var` or `val`, then they have no existence beyond the constructor at all. If size of an instance matters, be aware of whether your non-property constructor parameters are referenced in method bodies.

Comment: Also, scope and accessibility are different things.

Comment: @RandallSchulz how is it possible then that this Scala code compiles and works? (https://gist.github.com/gnapse/96387a056f0cf45dac7a). The `fake` argument of the `Testing` class is not prefixed by `val` or `var` and it is still accessible inside instance methods (check out the `output` method), not just in the constructor code.

Comment: Scala compiler will emit a private field in this case, if you look at the resulting bytecode you will see `private final Z fake`.

Answer (score 11):

This

```
class Person(val name: String, val age: Int)
```

makes the fields available externally to users of the class e.g. you can later do

```
val p = new Person("Bob", 23)
val n = p.name
```

If you specify the args as `var`, then the scoping is the same as for `val`, but the fields are mutable.

Answer (score 8):

If you are familiar with Java, you can get the idea from this example:

```
class Person(name: String, age: Int)
```

is similiar to

```
class Person {
  public Person(String name, int age) {
  }
}
```

While

```
class Person(var name: String, var age: Int) // also we can use 'val'
```

is similar to

```
class Person {
  String name;
  int age;

  public Person(String name, int age) {
     this.name = name;
     this.age = age;
  }
}
```

The intuition is that without var/val, the variable is only accessible inside the constructor. If var/val is added, the class will have the member variables with the same name.

Comment: The first comparision is not completely right. In the Java code you just can call the parameters `name` and `age` in the constructor, not in other class methods, but in Scala you can. The similar code in Java would be:
`class Person {
  private String name;
  private int age;

  public Person(String name, int age) {
     this.name = name;
     this.age = age;
  }
}`

Comment: Addition: The two fields are immutable, too.

Answer (score 2):

The answers here are really good, however I'm tackling this one with exploring the byte code. When you apply `javap` on a class, it prints out package, protected, and public fields and methods of the classes passed. I created a class Person.scala and filled it out with the following code.

```
class Person(name: String, age: Int) {
  def say = "My name is " + name + ", age " + age
}

class PersonVal(val name: String, val age: Int) {
  def say = "My name is " + name + ", age " + age
}

class PersonVar(var name: String, var age: Int) {

  age = happyBirthday(5)

  def happyBirthday(n: Int) = {
    println("happy " + n + " birthday")
    n
  }
}
```

After compiling the code with `scalac Person.scala` it generates three files with names `Person.class, PersonVal.calass , PersonVar.cass`. By running `javap` for each of these class files we can see how the structure would be:

```
>>javap Person.class
Compiled from "Person.scala"
public class Person {
  public java.lang.String say();
  public Person(java.lang.String, int);
}
```

In this case it didn't create any class varible for Person since it is declared with neither val, nor val so name and age can just be used inside constructor.

```
>>javap PersonVal.class
public class PersonVal {
  public java.lang.String name();
  public int age();
  public java.lang.String say();
  public PersonVal(java.lang.String, int);
}
```

In this case it has three members two for the input constructor and one for the member that we declared inside the constructore. However we don't have any setter for the input constructors so we can't change the values.

```
>>javap PersonVar.class
public class PersonVar {
  public java.lang.String name();
  public void name_$eq(java.lang.String);
  public int age();
  public void age_$eq(int);
  public int happyBirthday(int);
  public PersonVar(java.lang.String, int);
}
```

It's the same as PersonVal example but we can change the values in this case  with those `variable_$eq` methods. it nothing just a shortened version of `variable =`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `case class` and in that case the `Person` class would have those variables available outside of the class. 
`case class Person(name: String, age: Int)`. Then the following code would work as expected. `val z = new Person("John", 20); z.name //John`

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Reza where the author explores byte code using javap helped me to clarify this concept the best. To cite a very specific example of this case please refer to below scenario that I faced in my production web app (Play + Scala):
[How to inject parameters into a class/trait method in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49034562/how-to-inject-parameters-into-a-class-trait-method-in-scala)

If I don't use val prefix to injected parameter `authorizationHandler` then 
compiler throws this error:

```
class MyController needs to be abstract, since method authorizationHandler in trait AuthorizationCheck of type => controllers.authapi.AuthorizationHandler is not defined
[error] class MyController @Inject() (authorizationHandler: AuthorizationHandler) extends Controller with AuthorizationCheck {
[error]       ^
[error] one error found
```

Sadly the error didn't help me to pinpoint to the correct issue which is to prefix with `val`.

```
class MyController @Inject()(val authorizationHandler: AuthorizationHandler) extends Controller with AuthorizationCheck {

   def myAction = AuthenticatedAction { implicit request =>
     ...
   }
}
```