# Scala Constructor Parameters

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

What is the difference between a private var constructor parameter and a constructor parameter without val/var? Are they same in terms of scope/visibility?

Ex:

```
class Person(private var firstName:String, lastName:String)
```

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639078/scala-class-constructor-parameters

Comment: This has a better explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694712/do-scala-constructor-parameters-default-to-private-val

Answer (score 30):

Yes, there are two important differences. First for the easy one: constructor parameters without the `var` or `val` keywords are not mutable variables—their values can't be changed in the body of the class.

Even if we restrict ourselves to the `val` keyword, though, there's still a difference between `private val` and keyword-less parameters. Consider the following:

```
class Person(private val firstName: String, lastName: String)
```

If we look at the compiled class with `javap -v Person`, we'll see that it only has one field, for `firstName`. `lastName` is just a constructor parameter, which means it may be garbage-collected after the class is initialized, etc.

The compiler is smart enough to know when the value of `lastName` will be needed after initialization, and it will create a field for it in that case. Consider the following variation:

```
class Person(private val firstName: String, lastName: String) {
  def fullName = firstName + " " + lastName
}
```

The compiler can tell that it may need the value of `lastName` later, and if we check `javap` again we'll see that the class has two fields (note that if we'd defined `fullName` as a `val` instead of a `def`, it'd only have one field).

Lastly, note that if we make `firstName` *object-private* instead of *class-private*, it works exactly like a plain old keyword-less constructor parameter:

```
class Person(private[this] val firstName: String, lastName: String)
```

This works even with `var` instead of `val`:

```
class Person(private[this] var firstName: String, lastName: String)
```

Both of these classes will have no fields. See section 5.2 of [the language specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/sites/default/files/linuxsoft_archives/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) for more details about object-private access.

Comment: Are you saying that in situations such as the example with `def fullName` there is no difference between a **`private val`** and a keyword-less parameter?

Comment: @TravisBrown In 2.13.2 both `class Person(private[this] val firstName: String)` and `class Person(firstName: String)` generate field `private[this] val firstName: String` https://stackoverflow.com/a/62686327/5249621

Answer (score 1):

as a supplement, if your class is a case class, all of the constructor parameters will be automatically public fields.

The compiler will complain about the private keyword if it exists, and for the parameters without val/var, no matter they are used or not in any defs, there will be public fields generated for them.