# Scala - val parameters

Tags: scala, inheritance, case-class

Let's say I have an

```
object Error{
    abstract class Reason{def p:P}
    case class A(p:P) extends Reason
    case class B(p:P) extends Reason
    ...
}
```

And that now I want to add a special case of B:

```
object Error{
    abstract class Reason{def p:P}
    case class A(p:P) extends Reason
    class B(val p:P) extends Reason{
        def apply(p:P) = new B(p)
        def unappply(b:B) = 
            if(b == null) None
            else Some(b.p)
    }

    case class SpecialB(override val p:P) extends B(p)
    ...
}
```

In this change, why must I declare parameter p in B as val and why didn't I have to when B was a case class?

Answer (score 2):

All parameters of a case class constructor are exposed as public values, which is not the case for a plain class, for which `val` must be used to make the parameter public.

Answer (score 1):

In a case class when you provide constructor parameter `p`, a field with public getter method with same signature as `def p:P` is created.

In a regular class you have to specify that parameter should have public methods via `val` or `var`. Otherwise it can be discarded after initialization. 
See [Scala Constructor Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623687/scala-constructor-parameters)