# Does the arguments in the constructor of a subclass get duplicated in parent class?

Tags: scala, memory, attributes, class-hierarchy

In the code below:

```
class A(val a: Int, val b: Int)

class B(a: Int, b: Int, val c: Int) extends A(a,b)
```

Are the variable `a` and `b`, or pointers to them, duplicated in memory when creating an instance of `B`?

Or more generally: does a B takes more memory than the memory size of A + an Int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Scala Constructor Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623687/scala-constructor-parameters).

and

[Do scala constructor parameters default to private val?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694712/do-scala-constructor-parameters-default-to-private-val)

`a` and `b` in class `B` are not available outside the constructor of `B` and do not override anything in class `A`