# Initialization of class members using constructor parameters

Tags: scala

I would like to create a class that only holds single-digit numbers.

```
class onlyLikesSingleDigits(val anyNumber: Seq[Int]) {
  val onlySingleDigits = anyNumber.filter(_ < 10)
}
```

The idea is you can construct it, and any numbers greater than or equal to 10 that you pass into the constructor would just be discarded.

My implementation looks rather ugly. Can't I do this without using `anyNumber`? I want to initialize my class using the constructor parameters as input to the `filter`, not as actual members of the class.

How can I do this with only a single `val`?

Comment: if you want only filtered elements, why not use filtered sequence as constructor argument directly? the example is a bit artificial.

Comment: @Ashalynd How would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `val` from `anyNumber` and it won't be member of the class. Maybe you'll find this helpful: [scala class constructor parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639078/scala-class-constructor-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

You should better separate the data representation from constructor logic by using Factory pattern.

Data representation

```
scala> case class OnlyLikesSingleDigits(digits: Seq[Int])
```

Factory

```
object DigitsMaker { 
  def apply(anyNums: Seq[Int]) = OnlyLikesSingleDigits(anyNums.filter(_ < 10)) 
}
```

Usage

```
scala> val r = DigitsMaker(Seq(4, 12, 5, 76))
r: OnlyLikesSingleDigits = OnlyLikesSingleDigits(List(4, 5))
```