# why the class's members should be add "var"/"val" or we could not visit them?

Tags: scala

why the class's members should be add "var"/"val" or we could not visit them?

in scala, if we declare a class like this, it will compile error.

```
class A(a : Int) {}
val x = new A(3)
x.a // compile error
```

if we add val to the member a:

```
class A(val a : Int) {}
val x = new A(3)
x.a // compile pass
```

What is the difference between the two class ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [scala class constructor parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639078/scala-class-constructor-parameters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First definition describes a class with constructor parameter (not member) `a` - you can use it inside constructor:

```
class A(a : Int) {
   //---default constructor body starts---
   val aa = a 
   //---default constructor body ends---
}

scala> val a = new A(5)
a: A = A@2ed2e591

scala> a.aa
res6: Int = 5

scala> a.a
<console>:10: error: value a is not a member of A
              a.a
            ^
```

Second describes a class with `a` as both constructor parameter and member. It's equivalent to:

```
class A(_a : Int) {
   val a = _a 
}
```