# What is val at class parameter in Scala?

Tags: scala

I see something like below sometimes.

```
class Test(val str: String){
}
```

I wrote some sample code with `val` though, I don't see any difference between common declaration and the way with `val`.

What is the difference between them? 
and When should it be used?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you add `val`, your variable will be visible from outside of class.

```
// 'name' is a val
class Person(val name: String)
val p = new Person("Alvin Alexander")
p.name                                  // String = Alvin Alexander
p.name = "Fred Flintstone"              // error: reassignment to val

// 'name' is neither var or val
class Person(name: String)
val p = new Person("Alvin Alexander")
p.name                                  // error: value name is not a member of Person
```

The code was taken from http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-class-examples-constructors-case-classes-parameters

More info [scala class constructor parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639078/scala-class-constructor-parameters)

Answer (score 4):

By adding to @EntryLevelDev's answer, you can use `javap` to see what really happened.

1.scala

```
class Test(val str: String){
}
```

step1. scalac 1.scala

step2. javap Test

Compiled from "1.scala"

```
public class Test {
  public java.lang.String str();
  public Test(java.lang.String);
}
```

2.scala :

```
class Test2(str: String){
    }
```

step1. scalac 2.scala

step2. javap Test2

Compiled from "1.scala"

```
public class Test1 {
  public Test1(java.lang.String);
}
```

So when you add val, scala generates a method by the argument's name, and is made public so is visible from outside.

Comment: I like this explanation very much!